# Adding comments to database columns and retrieving from AWS Glue

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I'm trying to incorporate a AWS GLUE Data Catalog to my Data Lake I'm building out. I'm using a few different databases and would like to add COMMENTS to columns in a few of these tables. These databases include Redshift and MySql. I usually add the comments to the column by doing something along the lines of

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN table.column_name IS 'This is the comment';
```

Now i know that Glue has a comment field that shows in the GUI. Is there a way to sync the comment field in Glue with the comments I add to the columns in a DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to update some meta information about a table that has been defined in AWS Glue Data Catalog, you would need to use a combination of [`get_table()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.get_table) and [`update_table()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.update_table) methods with [`boto3`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html) for example .

Here is the most naive approach to do that:

```py
import boto3
from pprint import pprint

glue_client = boto3.client('glue')

database_name = "__SOME_DATABASE__"
table_name = "__SOME_TABLE__"

response = glue_client.get_table(
    DatabaseName=database_name,
    Name=table_name
)
original_table = response['Table']
```

Here `original_table` adheres response syntax defined by `get_table()`. However, we need to remove some fields from it so it would pass validation when we use `update_table()`. List of allowed keys could be obtained by passing `original_table` directly to `update_table()` without any chagnes

```py
allowed_keys = [
    "Name",
    "Description",
    "Owner",
    "LastAccessTime",
    "LastAnalyzedTime",
    "Retention",
    "StorageDescriptor",
    "PartitionKeys",
    "ViewOriginalText",
    "ViewExpandedText",
    "TableType",
    "Parameters"
]
updated_table = dict()
for key in allowed_keys:
    if key in original_table:
        updated_table[key] = original_table[key]
```

For simplicity sake, we will change comment of the very first column from the table

```py
new_comment = "Foo Bar"
updated_table['StorageDescriptor']['Columns'][0]['Comment'] = new_comment

response = glue_client.update_table(
    DatabaseName=database_name,
    TableInput=updated_table
)

pprint(response)
```

Obviously, if you want to add a comment to a specific column you would need to extend this to

```py
new_comment = "Targeted Foo Bar"
target_column_name = "__SOME_COLUMN_NAME__"
for col in updated_table['StorageDescriptor']['Columns']:
    if col['Name'] == target_column_name:
        col['Comment'] = new_comment

response = glue_client.update_table(
    DatabaseName=database_name,
    TableInput=updated_table
)

pprint(response)
```

Comment: thanks for this, I can definitely see how this works. But by any chance, is there a way to map the comment section that mySql and Redshift have, to the comment section in AWS Glue? This way anytime a comment is added or changed, Glue updates it as well. I'm going the route of adding a trigger to the table

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59200724/aws-glue-customized-crawler Any ideas with this^^

Comment: No, sorry) My best guess is that it’s not possible to do on the client side. As I understand, glue crawler is about data schema discovery/definition. Whereas, comment is like a meta data.

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful